# Follow-up to UNION NULLS for What-IF View Comparator

Tags: sql-server, null, outer-join, cartesian-product

This question is a follow up to:

[purposely union'ing NULLs for a training matrix.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249262/union-nulls-into-view-that-can-be-queried-later)

In the prior thread, I mentioned a company with a Job Skills table and an Employee Skills table. For this discussion, let's use just two of the employees...

```
           jobskills          +             emplskills
job_code skill_desc skill_ID  |  empl_ID emplName job_code skill_ID
-------- ---------- --------  |  ------- -------- -------- --------
   APP      Cut        10     |    396     Tom       APP      10
   APP      Drill      20     |    396     Tom       APP      30
   APP      Bend       30     |    426     Bob       EXP      10
   EXP      Cut        10     |    426     Bob       EXP      20
   EXP      Drill      20     |    426     Bob       EXP      40
   EXP      Bend       30     |    426     Bob       EXP      50
   EXP      Weld       40     |
   EXP      Turn       50     |
                              +
```

In the `jobskills` table, you will see that the APP (apprentice) job title requires 3 skills - cutting, drilling, and bending (10, 20, 30). Likewise, the EXP (expert) job title requires 5 skills (10 thru 50).

In the `emplskills` table, you will see that Tom is an apprentice (APP) who should have all 3 skills for his job title but only has 2. He is missing the drilling skill (20). In the same fashion: Bob, who is an expert (EXP) should have all 5 skills in his job title but is missing the Bend skill (30).

In the prior post, @JuanCarlosOropeza created this query (I re-defined some columns) which outer joins NULLs per empl_ID to list all skills employees have and don't have.

```
WITH required_skills as 
(
     SELECT DISTINCT 
         e.empl_ID, e.job_code, j.skill_ID, j.skill_desc
     FROM 
         emplskills e
     JOIN 
         jobskills j ON e.job_code = j.job_code
)
SELECT 
    r.empl_ID, e.emplName, r.job_code, r.skill_ID, r.skill_desc
FROM 
    required_skills r
LEFT JOIN 
    emplskills e ON r.empl_ID = e.empl_ID
                 AND r.skill_ID = e.skill_ID;
```

The above query produces the results I need to compare an employee's skills to his own job title:

RESULT of query:

```
empl_ID emplName job_code skill_ID skill_desc
------- -------- -------- -------- ----------
  396     Tom       APP      10       Cut
  396     Tom       APP      20       Drill
  396    {null}     APP      30       Bend
  426     Bob       EXP      10       Cut
  426     Bob       EXP      20       Drill
  426    {null}     EXP      30       Bend
  426     Bob       EXP      40       Weld
  426     Bob       EXP      50       Turn
```

The point of this query is a Training application that uses this query as a source view. If a user filters on empl_ID, she can look at Tom (396) and see that he is missing the Bend skill (30)

Filter on Tom(396)

```
empl_ID emplName job_code skill_ID skill_desc
------- -------- -------- -------- ----------
  396     Tom       APP      10       Cut
  396     Tom       APP      20       Drill
  396    {null}     APP      30       Bend
```

...and now the **NEW QUESTION:**

In the training Application I need to compare an employee to ANY job title. So I need to outer join every employee with every possible combination of job_codes and every possible combination of skills.

The **desired result** of the query I really need is something like this:

```
empl_ID emplName job_code skill_ID skill_desc
------- -------- -------- -------- ----------
  396     Tom       APP      10       Cut
  396     Tom       APP      20       Drill
  396    {null}     APP      30       Bend
  396     Tom       EXP      10       Cut
  396     Tom       EXP      20       Drill
  396    {null}     EXP      30       Bend
  396    {null}     EXP      40       Weld
  396    {null}     EXP      50       Turn
  426     Bob       APP      10       Cut
  426     Bob       APP      20       Drill
  426     Bob       APP      30       Bend
  426     Bob       EXP      10       Cut
  426     Bob       EXP      20       Drill
  426    {null}     EXP      30       Bend
  426     Bob       EXP      40       Weld
  426     Bob       EXP      50       Turn
```

Now when the user filters, they can compare employees to requirements in different job titles. For Tom the apprentice, the original filtering on Apprentice title still works:

```
Filter on Tom(396) and JOB CODE (APP)
empl_ID emplName job_code skill_ID skill_desc
------- -------- -------- -------- ----------
  396     Tom       APP      10       Cut
  396     Tom       APP      20       Drill
  396    {null}     APP      30       Bend
```

However, if Tom is being considered for a promotion to EXPERT, the manager can immediately see what expert skills Tom would be short on:

```
Filter on Tom(396) and JOB CODE (EXP)
empl_ID emplName job_code skill_ID skill_desc
------- -------- -------- -------- ----------
  396     Tom       EXP      10       Cut
  396     Tom       EXP      20       Drill
  396    {null}     EXP      30       Bend
  396    {null}     EXP      40       Weld
  396    {null}     EXP      50       Turn
```

Is there a way to alter the above query to accomplish this? I can't thank you guys enough on the help you've provided so far. This is a real-life challenge at my current job. We have around 150 actual factory workers across 40+ job titles. Some of these job titles have more than 3 dozen skill_IDs associated with them.

Lastly, I tried to CREATE VIEW AS () with the above query but couldn't get the syntax right. After we have the new query working, can you help me convert it to a CREATE VIEW statement?

Thanks again,
John

Comment: Sounds like you need a full outer join. And to turn a query into a view is about as simple as CREATE VIEW MyView as ....put your query here...

Comment: @SeanLange When I change the query above to `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` I get the same 8-row results as the query above.

Comment: As which above? There are several results shown.

Comment: Hi @SeanLange, near the top of the post there is one `WITH ... SELECT DISTINCT` statement. Directly under that statement is an 8-row query result. That's the result I get as well with the `FULL OUTER JOIN` change

Comment: @SeanLange When I wrap the above query with `CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW AS (...)` I get a syntax error on the `WITH`, but no explanation. – John Joseph

Comment: How about sharing the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Oh I bet I know what the problem with the view is. You are probably starting your cte with a semicolon. ;with....the cte requires that the previous statement be terminated with a semicolon. As a result MANY of the examples of ctes start the statement with a semicolon. That will cause a problem with a view because only a single statement is allowed. The semicolon is a statement **terminator** not a **beginninator**. Drop the leading ; and it will most likely work.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks. I'll post a separate new question about the CREATE VIEW syntax. For this post could we stick to converting the WITH AS (SELECT DISTINCT) SELECT LEFT JOIN sql statement above to the FULL OUTER JOIN you suggested please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be posting data in a consumable format. Fortunately Juan Carlos Opreza did that for you in your previous question. I took his and removed the "extra" data from your other question.

```
CREATE TABLE emplskills 
    ([empl_ID] int, [emplName] varchar(3), [job_code] varchar(3), [skill_ID] int)
;

INSERT INTO emplskills 
    ([empl_ID], [emplName], [job_code], [skill_ID])
VALUES
    (396, 'Tom', 'APP', 10),
    (396, 'Tom', 'APP', 20),
    (426, 'Bob', 'EXP', 10),
    (426, 'Bob', 'EXP', 20),
    (426, 'Bob', 'EXP', 40),
    (426, 'Bob', 'EXP', 50)
;


CREATE TABLE jobskills 
    ([job_code] varchar(3), [skill_desc] varchar(5), [skill_ID] int)
;

INSERT INTO jobskills 
    ([job_code], [skill_desc], [skill_ID])
VALUES
    ('APP', 'Cut', 10),
    ('APP', 'Drill', 20),
    ('APP', 'Bend', 30),
    ('EXP', 'Cut', 10),
    ('EXP', 'Drill', 20),
    ('EXP', 'Bend', 30),
    ('EXP', 'Weld', 40),
    ('EXP', 'Turn', 50)
;
```

Now that we have something concrete and definitive to work with let's see how this might work. Since a left join doesn't work because you are making empl_ID be populated when there isn't a match you need a little different approach. There is more than one way to tackle this. I used a cross join to generate a list of all employees and jobskills. That gives us your list that we can use in a left join.

I have to say that you need to read up on normalization as these structures are rather painful.

```
select AllEmpSkills.empl_ID
    , es.emplName
    , js.job_code
    , js.skill_ID
    , js.skill_desc
from jobskills js
cross join 
(
    select distinct empl_ID from emplskills
) AllEmpSkills
left join emplskills es on es.empl_ID = AllEmpSkills.empl_ID
                    and es.skill_ID = js.skill_ID
order by AllEmpSkills.empl_ID
    , js.job_code
    , js.skill_ID
```

Comment: awesome! I dropped the order by clause and made a view out of that. Works perfectly. Thank you so much again.

Comment: The most important thing though is that you understand why it works. Don't hesitate to ask if you there is a part you don't get. Glad you were able to use this.

Comment: ok I see the cross is every possible combination of empl_ID and skill_ID first. Then the left join. I'm not very good with compound selects so thanks again.

Comment: Yeah sounds like you understand it. Seeing things like this and understanding them will help you figure out how to conjure them yourself. :D